# LFI Why would I not see a response

Tags: php, centos, ctf

I have the below two vulnerable PHP code sections in 2 files. I found the sources of these in an anony access FTP backup file `home.tar.gz`.

So I'm getting the content of `/etc/passwd` with the null byte terminator `%00` on both these section of code. i.e `../../../../../etc/passwd%00`

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The main problem here to resolve is to not use user-submitted data in such way that based on submitted value in Cookie "user" the file is included, even if it has "rtps/" and ".txt" added this doesn't change much. The "user" variable should be stored on server side and user should have randomized (256bit) cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first piece of code directly attempts to include the file conatined in the $doc variable.

```
<?php include $doc;?>
```

The second piece of code makes a file_exists() call and depending on the result of this call, attempts to include the file.

```
file_exists($finc)
```

file_exists is [subject to PHP safe mode restrictions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). These provide means to prevent the inclusion of specific files/directories that would otherwise be accessible. As stated in the PHP docs, PHP is not the appropriate place in the stack to enforce such restrictions, but this is a fallback mechanism should appropriate hardening and design/configuration practices not be present at the web server and/or OS level.

With the above in mind, you will be better able to perform LFI in the first code sample.